# If $\mathbb{E} e^{it(X+Y)} = \mathbb{E} e^{itX} \mathbb{E} e^{itY}$ then $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated

Tags: probability, probability-theory, characteristic-functions

Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables such that 
$\mathbb{E} e^{it(X+Y)} = \mathbb{E} e^{itX} \mathbb{E} e^{itY}$ and covariance exists.

I want to show that they are uncorrelated, i.e., $\mathbb{E}(X -\mathbb{E}X) (Y - \mathbb{E}Y) = 0$.
According to this paper https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1198/tast.2009.09051?needAccess=true, this is true.
I can prove it when both have finite second moments, but I do not know how I should proceed for general general random variables. Any hints or reference are appreciated.

Differentiating $\varphi_{X+Y}(t) = \varphi_X(t) \varphi_Y(t) $ twice and letting $t=0$,  \begin{equation} \varphi_X ''(0) \varphi_Y(0) + 2 \varphi_X'(0) \varphi_Y'(0) + \varphi_X(0) \varphi_Y''(0) = \varphi_{X+Y}''(0) \end{equation}
Since \begin{equation}  \varphi_X^{(k)}(t) = \mathbb{E} (( iX)^k e^{itX})\end{equation} holds for $X \in L^k$, 
\begin{equation} \mathbb{E} ( iX)^2 + 2 \mathbb{E} ( iX) \mathbb{E} ( iY)+\mathbb{E} ( iY)^2 = \mathbb{E} (i^2(X+Y)^2) \end{equation}

Comment: What about $X = Y \sim \operatorname{Cauchy}(0,1)$?

Comment: @RhysSteele One instance of subindependence is when a random variable X is Cauchy with mean 0 and scale s and another random variable Y=X. Then X+Y is also Cauchy but with scale 2s. The characteristic function of either X or Y in t is then exp(-s·|t|), and the characteristic function of X+Y is exp(-2s·|t|). http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Subindependence

Comment: Yes, that was my point. The Cauchy random variable does not have finite second moment and in particular for $X=Y \sim \operatorname{Cauchy}(0,1)$ we do not have $\mathbb{E}[(X - \mathbb{E}X)^2] = 0$ (i.e. that $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated) but we do have subindependence. Is this not a counterexample to the general claim?

Comment: @RhysSteele Yes. Thank you. I will edit my claim.